# Rails: Calling a controller method from another controller -> NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller, nomethoderror

I am using the Devise gem and have the 2 controllers:

1: controllers/admin/mailings_controller.rb:

```
class Admin::MailingsController < ApplicationController
  def self.send_emails
    ...
    RegistrationsController.create
    ...
  end
end
```

2: controllers/registrations_controller.rb:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  ...
  # POST
  def create
     # do some stuff
     super
     # do some stuff
  end
  ...
end
```

But when I execute (in the console)...

```
Admin::MailingsController.send_emails
```

...I get...

```
"NoMethodError: undefined method `create' for RegistrationsController:Class"
```

Why? And how to fix this?

```
rake routes
```

...shows no problem:

```
user_registration POST  ->  /users(.:format)  ->  registrations#create
```

Comment: Try `RegistrationsController.new.create`.. Although what it looks like you're trying to do is not really correct. Are you trying to redirect?

Comment: Or modify your create function : `def create` -> `def self.create`, it'll make your function static and can be call through class name

Comment: controller methods are not simply methods but `actions`, mean to respond to http requests. Do not treat controllers like usual ruby modules/classes holding some code. Keep your code which you want to call from multiple controllers in a separate module, and include that module in all those controllers. and call modules methods

Comment: No, I'm not trying to redirect, just to re-use a part of already existing code from the Devise gem. And the method "send_mails" is to be used only 1 time (at launch), so I guess it's ok to do it like this. Thank you all for your help - the first to post it as a reply gets accepted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `RegistrationsController.create` to `RegistrationsController.new.create`

OR

change `def create` to `def self.create`.

The confusion you have here is using a class method where you mean to call an instance method. You can remedy this by either calling the method on an instance or changing the method to a class method.

Comment: Keep in mind that the request isn't present in RegistrationsController when you do it this way.